# update records on table with millions record

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

We have table of 9 columns and pk is indexed. we have 169.3 Millions records which could go up to 250M. Every time I receive update I have to fetch about 40,000 rows from database to compare using another indexed column name fk. after I process I have:

```
pk_update_nc = [pk1, pk2, pk5, .....pk40000]
pk_update_PN = [pk3, pk4, pk6, .....pk35090]
new_rows = [[row1], [row2], [row3], [row40000]]
```

above data simply suggest:

> update table and set column status = 'NC' whose type is varying
>   character(3) where pk in pk_update_nc update table and set column
>   status = 'PN' whose type is varying character(3) where pk in
>   pk_update_PN
>
> insert rows to table from new_rows

What will be the best way to update and insert?

Method1:

```
start_transaction:
for pk in pk_update_nc:
    update table set status='NC' where table.pk = pk
for pk in pk_update_PN:
    update table set status='PN' where table.pk = pk
for row in new_rows:
    insert into table row = row
commit
```

Method2:

```
start_transaction;
update table set status='NC' where table.pk in pk_update_nc;
update table set status='PN' where table.pk in pk_update_PN;
insert into table values rows
commit
```

Method3:

```
fill list of updated records list with rows instead of complete records,
insert all records to table
start_transaction:
delete from table where fk = fk_provided;
insert all rows, updated + new using \copy or django bulk create
commit;
```

> - Explanation as requested for third method.*  This mean fetch rows from database and process locally which is normal in every method, now
>     instead of update database, we change old records consider them new.
>     delete all records from database   having fk which is indexed column,
>     then insert all records as new using \copy. \copy insert records
>     magically fast. for \copy visit [postgresql COPY-TO/COPY-FROM](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html)

Method4?
Suggest

**FAQ:**

> Why should I pull 40,000 rows from db?
>
> It's because we have to process these records against new records to
>   form status of old&new records, old rows are passed from many use
>   cases to final their status. This conclude multiple hits for each row
>   and impact performance hit. that's why I decided to pull data and
>   process locally before final update. Now we want minimal possible hit
>   of performance to update db.
>
> concurrency problems:
>
> We resolve this by locking sheet to be processed. and next sheet for
>   same records is locked to be processed until previous task is
>   completed. this restrict users to process same fk sheet to be
>   processed simultaneously. Questions on database could be, Should I
>   lock database while updating and processing which could take up-to 1-2
>   minutes? database could be locked for update only which takes lesser
>   time.
>
> tools:

- psql postgresql 9.1 python 2.7 django 1.5

Comment: Why do you have to pull 40,000 rows down the client, why can't postgre do it for you, it's good at that sort of thing.

Comment: Could you elaborate on Method 3?  Out of Method 1 and 2, I think Method 2 would be much faster because you are only calling one SQL command for each operation as opposed to one for each record in each operation.

Comment: @JustinHui If Explanation is enough?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to put lipstick on a pig.

It is *extremely* inefficient to retrieve 40k rows, manipulate them in some client application and write them back. On top of that, you easily run into concurrency problems in multi-user environment. What if something changed in the database while you have been toying with the data in your app? How to resolve such conflicts?

The proper way to do this (if at all possible) is to do it inside the database with set-based operations.

[**Data-modifying CTEs**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) are particularly useful for more complex operations manipulating data in multiple tables. [This search here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D%20%5Bsql-update%5D%20url:%22http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING%22) comes up with a few examples.

Comment: among 40k records each record is compared against his new records. This means min 40k hits for old records and 40k inserts. This conclude min 80,000 hits to highly loaded table, Is it recommended? Best Practice could be but should I lock database to support concurrency? Is locking database feasible and efficient practice?